# What is the actual difference of Azure Notification Hubs' Telemetry options?

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub

While researching Azure Notification Hubs, I saw there are two Telemetry options available ([source](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/notification-hubs/)):

- "Limited"
- "Rich"

Although I have found very limited descriptions on the [Pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/notification-hubs/) and the [FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-faq) pages, this is not enough information to make a decision whether I want the "Rich" telemetry or if the "Limited" Telemetry is enough. Additionaly, those descriptions only talk about the "Rich" option:

> Standard namespaces have access to Per Message Telemetry and Push Notification Services Feedback
>
> Rich telemetry: You can use Notification Hubs Per Message Telemetry to track any push requests and Platform Notification System Feedback for debugging.

Also, a [Tweet](https://twitter.com/Structed/status/855128779542450176) asking [@AzureSupport](https://twitter.com/AzureSupport) for help only lead to the [FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-faq) page and eventually led them to ask me if I could ask this very question on SO.

The only option available next to asking here is to actually try out, but that would incur a monthly fee and extra effort.

Comment: and still, this is not a SO question. Check with FAQ and how to ask questions. You will find out better and more accurate information if you try both options and compare. It does not cost ton of money...

Comment: It does if you not only consider the service's price, but also manpower. Perhaps someone from Microsoft is able to answer this question or someone else has made this comparison but I can't find it because it is buried inside something else or not yet published. I will gladly do a deeper research if I cannot get the answer I am looking for here within reasonable time and post back my findings once I did.

Comment: even if so, StackOverflow is place to ask questions **directly related to programming**. And in your question there is nothing about programming.

Comment: Well, that is your view. I am personally interested in programming against this service and I will need to analyse and debug my software, therefore I need telemetry and therefore I need to know this. You can flag this question and let a editor decide if you wish so. Otherwise, it will just stick here and will eventually be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found [a useful MSDN page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/notificationhubs/get-notification-message-telemetry#outcomes), which has some answers to what telemetry is provided, how, and to who.  It says "This API is only available for Standard tier notification hubs" which means Rich Telemetry only, not Limited.

If the PNS platform involved supports it, then Success means it was delivered to the device.  Oddly, despite copious other error codes, there seems to be none for "accepted by PNS, but still not/failed to deliver to device."

It provides counts of outcomes, so if you want per-device results, you'll have to send to only to one device at a time.

Answer (score 2):

The main difference between the two is that "limited" gives you access to counts of various events: registrations, sends etc; pretty much everything you see as graphs in Azure Portal on Notification Hubs blades.

"Rich" (or Per Message Telemetry) gives you access to detailed information about every single push: things like feedback from PNS and many other things. You can think about it as if you were to send requests directly to PNS yourself and log pretty much any meaningful information about those.

Let me know in the comments if I can clarify.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is enough for me right now to start developing with the "standard" tier - and therefore with "Rich" telemetry and later downgrade if I don't need the additional volume that comes with that tier not the extra telemetry.

Comment: Rich telemetry is pretty useless as it is not in the portal or supported in any sdks other than the .net.